# Título de un Spinner Android, con estética diferente para los ítems del mismo y el título ( Spinner personalizado )

Tags: android, spinner

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que utilizo varios *Spinners* personalizados, a los que añado el título de cada uno de ellos.

En estos momentos me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría que saliera así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, primeramente recupero los registros desde una base de datos, con éste código:

```
// *** Llenar Spinner Establecimientos
public List<String> getAllTiendas() {
    List<String> tiendasSpnr = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblTiendas WHERE baja = " + 0 + "   ORDER BY nombre";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursorTda = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursorTda.moveToFirst()) {
        // Titulo del Spinner y primer registro
        tiendasId.add("0");
        tiendasSpnr.add(txtSpinner); 
        do {
            tiendasId.add(cursorTda.getString(0));
            tiendasSpnr.add(cursorTda.getString(1));
        } while (cursorTda.moveToNext());
    }
    cursorTda.close();
    db.close();
    return tiendasSpnr;
}
// ***
```

Luego en la *Actividad* que usa el *Spinner*, intento darle formato al título así:

```
// *** (I) Llenar Spinner Establecimientos
private void loadSpinner() {
    DataBaseDB.txtSpinner = getResources().getString(R.string.lblEstablecimiento);
    DataBaseDB db = new DataBaseDB(getApplicationContext());
    // **** Establecimientos
    List<String> tiendasSpnr = db.getAllTiendas();
    ArrayAdapter<String> tiendaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, tiendasSpnr);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < tiendaAdapter.getCount(); i++){
        if (i == 0) {
            tiendaAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item_titulo);
        } else {
            tiendaAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        }
    }

    spnrTienda.setAdapter(tiendaAdapter);
    spnrTienda.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
}
// *** (F) Llenar Spinner Establecimientos
```

Answer (score 5):

El cambiar el color de  fondo del primer elemento dentro de un `Spinner` no se puede realizar mediante algún método del SDK, para esto se tiene que realizar un `Adapter` personalizado, en el cual definirías el color de fondo y color de texto de acuerdo a tus necesidades (ver método [getView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup))).

El constructor recibe el contexto y una lista de valores a mostrar dentro del `Spinner`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jorgesys 
 */
class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {       
    List<String> values;
    Context context;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> values){
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return values.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        if(pos==0) { //Primer elemento color Azul #39399F
            txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#39399F"));
            txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); //Texto color Blanco
        }else { //Otros elementos ...
            txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF9DC"));
            txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#39399F")); //Texto color Azul
        }
        txv.setText(values.get(pos));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Para usar este Adapter, simplemente configuralo a tu Spinner:

```
   spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listadeDatos));
```

para obtener algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado perfecto.

Comment: @CarlosA. Recuerda marcar como solución si la respuesta ayudo a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.