# ¿Cómo cambio el color del texto de un spinner en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Intenté de varias formas con text-color etc.. Pero no encuentro como cambiarlo.. No es el color de los ítems es el del texto del ítem seleccionado. Por ejemplo, el que se muestra en la imagen -seleccione uno- que esta en negro y lo quiero colocar en blanco [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal amigo, tuve ese problema justamente ayer, lo que hice fue crear un cumtom spinner mediente un `XML`.Use este para cambiar el color del texto antes de abrir el spinner (El nombre del `XML` es: `spinner_item`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/SpinnerCustom"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:gravity="left"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

Creo que te pone el color del `dropdownmenu` en blanco tambien, por lo que use otro `XML` para solucionarlo(Nombre del `XML`: `spinner_dropdown_item`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Posteriormente en codigo:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerHead=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,        
    R.layout.spinner_item,Head);
    spinnerHead.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    SpinnerHead.setAdapter(spinnerHead);
```

Ademas peudes cambiar el fondo del dropdown con la siguiente linea:
`android:popupBackground=""`que va dentro del spinner en el `XML`

Answer (score 1):

Si únicamente requieres cambiar el color a blanco podrías usar un tema adecuado, por ejemplo:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

o usar un custom Style con el color deseado:

```
style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
```

para esto se define un Style dentro de `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_spinner_text_color</item>
</style>
```

---

Si requieres algo más complejo,  tendrías que usar un Custom Spinner para que puedas cambiar sus propiedades,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revisa esta pregunta:

[Título de un Spinner Android, con estética diferente para los ítems del mismo y el título](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46606/t%C3%ADtulo-de-un-spinner-android-con-est%C3%A9tica-diferente-para-los-%C3%ADtems-del-mismo-y)