# Spinner personalizado Android

Tags: android, spinner

**Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer que un spinner tenga el fondo blanco y las letras negras. Es lo único que quiero, bien básico para ello hice un `style` para aplicarlo en el mismo:

```
<style name="estilo_spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blanco</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/negro</item>
</style>
```

Lo aplico:

```
          <Spinner
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/provincia"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            style="@style/estilo_spinner"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp" />
```

Pero, al momento de ejecutarlo, suceden dos cosas. La primera, es que el texto que debería mostrarse es como si estuviera en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo segundo, es que al presionar el `spinner` el `background` es negro y las letras son blancas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me dice qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma es mediante un Adapter personalizado y dentro del método `getView()` modificar los colores del texto y del fondo dentro de tu Spinner, ejemplo:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {        
        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
        //Color Fondo Blanco.
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        //Color Texto Negro.
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
        textView.setText(valores.get(pos));

        return view;
    }
```

Revisa el adapter en esta respuesta:

[Spinner personalizado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46890/95)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]